# 2D Matrix Rotation with Bilinear Interpolation

Tags: c, arrays, math, matrix, interpolation

I am having difficulty implementing Bilinear Interpolation of a rotated image. The image is represented as doubles in a 2D matrix. Below is the code I have been using. The image rotates correctly by the desired angle, however the interpolation does not seem to eliminate the 'jaggedness' of the output image as desired.

Can anyone identify the issue with my code?

```
// DimX & DimY are dimensions of input Image (Which has padded space for rotation)
// radian = angle as rad (2*PI*{angle in deg})/360)
// COGPosX & COGPosY are the Centre of Gravity pos for the Input Matrix
// SliceMatrix is the un-rotated input Matrix

// double cosine,sine,f1,f2,fval,p1,p2,p3,p4,rotX,rotY,xfloor,yfloor;
// double *sliceMatrix, *rotationMatrixInter;
// int x,y,dimX,dimY,COGPosX,COGPosY,rotatedX,rotatedY;   

cosine = (double)cos(radian);
sine = (double)sin(radian);

for(y=0;y<dimY;y++)
{
    for(x=0;x<dimX;x++)
    {
        // Calculate rotated Matrix positions
        rotatedX=(double)((x-COGPosX)*cosine)-((y-COGPosY)*sine)+COGPosX;
        rotatedY=(double)((x-COGPosX)*sine)+((y-COGPosY)*cosine)+COGPosY;

        rotX = (int)floor(rotatedX);
        rotY = (int)floor(rotatedY);

        xfloor = floor(rotatedX);
        yfloor = floor(rotatedY);

        if(rotX >=0 && rotY < dimX-1 && rotY >=0 && rotY < dimY-1 )
        {
            // BLI Calculation
            p1 = sliceMatrix[rotX+(dimX*rotY)];         // 0,0
            p2 = sliceMatrix[rotX+(dimX*(rotY+1))];     // 0,1
            p3 = sliceMatrix[(rotX+1)+(dimX*rotY)];     // 1,0
            p4 = sliceMatrix[(rotX+1)+(dimX*(rotY+1))]; // 1,1

            f1 = p1 + (p3-p1)*(rotatedX-xfloor);
            f2 = p2 + (p4-p2)*(rotatedX-xfloor);
            fval = f1 + (f2-f1)*(rotatedY-yfloor);

            rotationMatrixInter[x+(dimX*y)]= fval; 
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`?

Comment: I will edit the code to include the declarations for the snippet now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you don't really interpolate as expected. `rotatedX` and `rotatedY` are of type `int`; if you cast them to double, they remain integral values and the denominators

```
((double)(rotatedX+1.0)-(double)rotatedX))
((double)(rotatedX+1.0)-(double)rotatedX))
```

cancel out to be `1.0`, which means that no real interpolation as desired takes place, but `f1` and `f2` actually get assigned `p3` and `p4` respectively. The variables `rotatedX` and `rotatedY` would have to be of type `double`. After rotation, they would have to be rounded down and up (or just round down and add one) to get the four positions to sample the image data from, and the difference to the rounded values would govern the interpolation. This could be done as follows, where `floor` is supposed to round down.

```
double xfloor = floor(rotatedX);
double yfloor = floor(rotatedY);

f1 = p1 + (p3-p1)*(rotatedX-xfloor);
f2 = p2 + (p4-p2)*(rotatedX-xfloor);
fval = f1 + (f2-f1)*(rotatedY-yfloor);
```

Comment: Changed Code as in your answer however I am getting the same result

Comment: Just changing the type doesn't solve the issue; the denominators also would have to be changed; I will update the answer.

Comment: Updated my Code, Outputted image is now distorted

Comment: There was a bug in the interpolation. The first interpolation should be close to the value of `p1` if `rotatedX` is close to `xfloor` and close to the value of `p3` if `rotatedX` is close to `xfloor+1`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: This gives me an image however I'm not sure if either the effect is correct (but my image resolution is impacting it) or whether it is incorrect. Please see this image (http://i.imgur.com/3dCs8Gn.png) The right image is the original (after just rotation) and the left is the interpolated one.

Comment: I'm also not sure; the image looks a bit jagged. It could also be that the formulas are correct, but there is some accuracy problem. What happens if you multiply out the braces and factor out the values from which to interpolate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you give me an example?

Comment: Please add your current implementation to the question.

Comment: The code looks correct, but the image puzzles me a bit.

Comment: The code works, i'm not entirely sure where the error was, but as I was tidying up my code it must have altered my mistake!